# play recorded video in a loop on my site

Tags: javascript, websocket, streaming, video-streaming, html5-video

Im looking for a way to stream a recorded video to my website in a way that it will be played in a loop,
While each visitor on the webpage will get to see the same exact moment that the video is now on.

Kind of like a live feed only the feed will be a movie file.

How can i do that using PHP/JS/HTML

thanks

Answer (score 0):

I dont think you will be able to do it with PHP alone, you will be needing some kind of Streaming Server (Windows/Flash/Red/Wowza etc), or you will have to use Windows Media Encoder to simulate a live.